# Eclipse-Plugin with submenu. How to handle JavaProjects and Projects?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I want to write an Eclipse-plugin that performs an Action with a selected Project. I used the plugin Template with submenu. My plugin.xml looks like this :

```
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
   <objectContribution
         objectClass="org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project"
         id="testplugin2.contribution1">
      <menu
            label="Propertie Manager"
            path="additions"
            id="testplugin2.menu1">
         <separator
               name="group1">
         </separator>
      </menu>
      <action
            label="list all *.properties"
            class="testplugin2.popup.actions.ListPropertiesAction"
            menubarPath="testplugin2.menu1/group1"
            enablesFor="1"
            id="testplugin2.projectAction">
      </action>
   </objectContribution>
</extension>
```

this works fine for everything but javaProjects. It turns out that javaProjects are not Projects. I want this Action to appear when a javaProjects or a normal Projects is selected and not if something else is selected.

How can I make the submenu appeare exactly if a javaProject or a Project is selected?

Comment: I solved the Problem with a work-around. I made two Actions one for IJavaProjects and one for IProjects and forwarded them.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it, but maybe this works:

```
<objectcontribution ...>
    <visibility>
        <objectClass
            name="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject" />
    </visibility>
</objectContribution>
```

You can also try "enablement" instead of "visibility".

[eclipse help pages on popup menus](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_basicext_popupMenus.htm)

Comment: I tested it but I didn't work. If I just add the Tag than the Action doesn't appear at all. If I change objectcontribution objectclass="java.lang.Object" than the Action only appears for JavaProjects. It is not possible to add a second visibility-Tag and enablement didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the **adaptable** property of your object contribution is set to *true* (it defaults to *false*):

```
adaptable="true"
```

@iain suggestion to target the interface is also good practice.

Just tried your example and the menus were showing as expected on a Java project.

Always bear in mind adpatability to *org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource* in general to ensure your menus, actions to be consistently displayed and enabled (whatever the explorer or actual object class being rendered).

Finally, beware that the *org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus* extension point is deprecated.

Though in my experience using it is faster and easier than the recommended *org.eclipse.ui.commands*, you may end up having a hard time migrating all your menus when it is removed (that is, ***if*** it is removed at some point).

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You should not reference the internal class in you object class.  You should use the public interface instead

```
objectClass="org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project"
```

Try

```
objectClass="org.eclipse.core.IProject"
```

I haven't tried this but `IJavaProject` should adapt to the `IProject`, so this should work for both.

Comment: I tested it and I did not work. I think you mean org.eclipse.core.ressources.IProject and this is suprisingly not a superinterface of org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject.