# Add popup action for Java projects in an Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I want to add popup item for Java projects in my Eclipse plugin. My plugin.xml contains:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
  <objectContribution
        objectClass="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject"
        id="com.contribution1">
     <action
           label="Action"
           class="com.actions.NewAction"
           enablesFor="1"
           id="com.actions.newAction">
     </action>
  </objectContribution>
```

However, the menu item is not shown in the popup. If I use IPackageFragment instead, the menu item shows just fine. Please advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118784/eclipse-plugin-with-submenu-how-to-handle-javaprojects-and-projects

Comment: Yeah, I found that thread before I posted this question but it didn't quite cover my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that a Java project is considered an IJavaProject in the Java perspective only and the Eclipse instance used to test the plugin starts with the Resources perspective. If I switch to the Java perspective everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display your menu in another explorer (for instance in the Resources perspective's Project explorer), you'll have to change your objectContribution definition as follows:

1. Set the **objectclass** property  to *org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject*.
2. Add a **visibility** element to filter your menu/actions for projects that **DO NOT** have the *Java nature*.

I.e:

```
<objectContribution
      adaptable="true"
      objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
...
   <visibility>
      <objectState
            name="projectNature"
            value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature">
      </objectState>
   </visibility>
</objectContribution>
```

Comment: Forgot to add, that as the _org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus_ extension point  is deprecated I would recommend to use _org.eclipse.ui.commands_ instead.